# Point not mapping properly from numpy array to PIL Image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am finding a point within a numpy array and then want to save this array as an image with a box around the located point.

Below is a simplified code representation showing the issue

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np

np_img = np.zeros((259,339,3))
pt = (29,118)

np_img[pt] = [255,0,0]
print(np_img[pt])

final_img = Image.fromarray(np_img, 'RGB')
#final_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(final_img)
#final_draw.rectangle([(pt[1]-3, pt[0]+3), (pt[1]+3, pt[0]-3)], outline="blue")

new_np_img = np.asarray(final_img)
print(new_np_img[pt])

new_pt = np.where(new_np_img > 0)
print(new_pt)

final_img.show()
```

I would expect that if I read the generated PIL image back into a numpy array that the point that I set as [255,0,0] would still be that value but it is not.  What is PIL doing to my data so that I can understand how I need to condition my numpy array so that it displays the correct position of my point in the PIL image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for undesired output is because you didn't explicitly defined the datatype of the *numpy* array as `uint8`. In your code, the first array (*np_img*) was stored as `float64` datatype. And the array obtained from `PIL` (*final_img*) was of the datatype `uint8`. Which caused inconsistent results.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

np_img = np.zeros((259,339,3), np.uint8)
pt = (29,118)

np_img[pt] = [255,0,0]
print(np_img[pt])

final_img = Image.fromarray(np_img, 'RGB')

new_np_img = np.asarray(final_img)
print(new_np_img[pt])

final_img.show()
```

**Output:-**

```
[255   0   0]
[255   0   0]
```

**Output Image:-**

[image]

Comment: Ahh I didn’t think of that.  That explains the difference I was seeing when comparing the numpy arrays but not why the highlighted point appears in an odd location in the PIL image ??  I expect the point to be in the top left of the image but it is appearing in the bottom right.

Comment: Sorry, I was driving and when I read your comment I didn't see that the datatype would effect the position of the point in the PIL image as well.  I ran your fix and it works perfect !